finding errors in docker-compose file task?
I have a task of finding the errors in this docker-compose.yaml file. I have included my answers, could someone tell me its correct and if I've found everything? The first is the yaml file and the below is my answer.
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/tmp/nginx.conf
    environment:
      - FLASK_SERVER_ADDR=backend
      - FLASK_SERVER_PORT=9091
    command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /tmp/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    build: flask
    environment:
      - MONGO_SERVER_PORT=27107
    volumes:
      - ./flask:/src
    depends_on:
      -  mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    command: mongo-express --admin --url mongodb://mongo:x
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_SITE_BASEURL=/

My answer:
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/tmp/nginx.conf
    environment:
      - FLASK_SERVER_ADDR=backend
      - FLASK_SERVER_PORT=9091
    command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /tmp/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    build: flask
    environment:
      - MONGO_SERVER_ADDR=mongo
      - MONGO_SERVER_PORT=27017
    volumes:
      - ./flask:/src
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      -  mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    command: mongo-express --admin --url mongodb://mongo:27017
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_SITE_BASEURL=/

Just wondering if I got it all correct
please give me some feedback

Can you please post your error here

Good guess.
There was an error with the mongoDB port.
MONGO_SERVER_PORT=27017
command: mongo-express --admin --url mongodb://mongo:27017
Be careful with indentation also.
